# How do I populate the identity column when inserting into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table whose data is inserted by selecting from another table. For example,

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID int, FirstName VARCHAR(100), LastName VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO TestTable (FirstName, LastName)
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Person.Contact
```

But How do I populate the ID? I tried

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (SCOPE_IDENTITY()+1, FirstName, LastName)
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Person.Contact
```

I don't want to make ID as identity column is because I duplicate the table structure from an exsiting one which the ID is regular column.

But it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Is the primary key set to auto increment? Because then you won't need to add the primary key field in your insert statement/

Comment: Can't you define ID as autoinc? What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the exact SQL server you're using, but since it appears you're using Microsoft SQL Server:

Simply labeling your column as `ID` is not enough.  You'll need to make sure that the `ID` column is marked in SQL Server as an Identity column.  This is similar to marking a column `SERIAL` in PostgreSQL, or `AUTOINCREMENT` in MySQL.  Make sure you've done this first.

Assuming you've done that, simply let the database itself add the identity value by explicitly not referencing that column in your `INSERT` statement.  Thus, something like

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (FirstName, LastName)
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Person.Contact
```

and relying on SQL Server's underlying identity support to fill it in for you will work fine.  It looks from your example like the thing you're missing is marking the `ID` column as an identity column in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

They are right in that you should specify a autonumber column.  As below:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable 
    (
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    Firstname varchar(100) NULL,
    Lastname varchar(100) NULL
    )
```

Then when you insert, use the following:

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table( ID int);
INSERT INTO TestTable
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
        INTO @MyTableVar
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Person.Contact;
```

Then you select @MyTableVar for the identities you inserted

Comment: I tried replace SCOPE_IDENTITY()+1 with @@identity, but got an error Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Is below what you are looking for?

SELECT
       id + 0
      ,FirstName
      ,LastName
   INTO test_table
   From Person.Contact